# How to use script in interactive shell

Tags: python

I wrote following python program

```
#! /usr/bin/python
def checkIndex(key):
    if not isinstance(key, (int, long)): raise TypeError
    if key<0: raise IndexError

class ArithmeticSequence:
    def __init__(self, start=0, step=1):
        self.start = start      # Store the start value
        self.step = step        # Store the step value
        self.changed = {}       # No items have been modified
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        checkIndex(key)
        try: return self.changed[key]
        except KeyError:
            return self.start + key*self.step
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        checkIndex(key)
        self.changed[key] = value
```

the program is my.py when I do

```
chmod +x my.py
python my.py
```

I am back to bash shell here after this step 
I open a python shell

```
user@ubuntu:~/python/$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:14:39) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> s=ArithmeticSequence(1,2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'ArithmeticSequence' is not defined
```

How do I give input to my program and run it because it was saved in vi

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: You have to import the module first: `>>> import my; s = my.ArithmeticSequence(1,2)`.

Comment: does the location of my program matters to import the module

Comment: I got import error import my.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named py

Comment: @RegisteredUser Yes, the location matters. You have to start the interpreter in the same directory where you have the script `my.py`.

Comment: Ok thanks I am able to get this up and running thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command that you want to run is:

```
python -i my.py
```

That will parse my.py and define the name `ArithmeticSequence`, and drop you into the Python shell where you can use your objects interactively:

```
>>> s=ArithmeticSequence(1,2)
>>>
```

Comment: your method python - scriptname.py does work , I used as some one suggested >>> import my and that also worked well, how ever I wrote another program then $bash]python -i some.py  works but doing with >>>import some and then running the interactive shell does not work here is the program http://pastebin.com/deQszXGJ and to run in interactive shell I just do r=Rectangle() in shell try with your method and method as some one else suggests

Comment: In case you know the reason as why the other method did not work let me know

Comment: You forgot to add #! to the beginning of that file on pastebin. Here's the fix: http://pastebin.com/6HqJcB5n

Comment: hmmm thanks for the fix but I tried the program and the other thing of imporiting as
 `>>>import some` does not work and I get error when I do a 
`r=Rectangle()` but the same thing (r=Rectangle) does not give an error when I import by python -i some

Comment: If using `import some` then you have to use `r=some.Rectangle()`.

Comment: ok this does work but why is this used this way and more over if you look at the original question if I used `>>>import my` then
`>>>s=ArithmeticSequence(1,2)` did not gave any error here I did not had to use `s=my.ArithmeticSequence(1,2)`

Comment: If you run `python -i my.py` then `ArithmeticSequence` exists in the *global* namespace and *not* in `my` module. If then you still `import my`, then `ArithmeticSequence` exists in *both*, global namespace *and* `my` module, in which case both `s = ArithmeticSequence(1,2)` and `s = my.ArithmeticSequence(1,2)` will work.

Answer (score 1):

Put your file my.py in PYTHONPATH 
then

```
from my import ArithmeticSequence
s=ArithmeticSequence(1,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you either have to run this as a program using

```
if __name__ == 'main':
    # Your code goes here. This will run when called from command line.
```

or if you are in the python interpreter you have to import "my" with:

```
>>> import my
```